# Triple integral, problem with bounds

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the following integral:

$\displaystyle\int\int\int_{V}z\sin(x^2+y^2)dxdydz$

$V$ is the solid limited by the surfaces:

$z=\cos(x^2+y^2)$, $z=0$ with $z\geq 0$

I cant write the limits of $V$ in the triple integral.

Here you have a plot of $z=\cos(x^2+y^2)$ for $x,y\in[-4,4]$:

[image]

Comment: Can you visualize the solid $V$? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I made a plot of $z=cos(x^2+y^2)$, let me deliver to you a link with a good image of it.

Comment: The graph in my “answer” (which is not a full answer) is the same as your graph, plotted with more points, and only showing the part above the $xy$-plane, since that’s what you need.

Comment: Does the region $V$ stretch infinitely far away from the origin, or is it bounded?

Comment: You are right about the plots, i would like to know what program or page did you used in this problem, if you dont mind.

Comment: Yes, $V$ stretch infinitely far away from the origin

Comment: I plotted this function with Mathematica. Here is the code: `Plot3D[{0, Cos[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -Sqrt[16 - x^2],Sqrt[16-x^2]}, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {0, 1.5}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of $cos(x^2+y^2)$ looks like this.

[image]

The value of $\cos(x^2+y^2)$ and of the term $\sin(x^2+y^2)$ in the integrand both depend on the square of the distance from $(x,y)$ to the origin (so they depend only on the distance). Where the “rings” start and end depend on when the distance from the origin is a value where $\cos$ is negative or not. The middle bump goes out to a radius $r$ from the origin where $r^2=\frac{\pi}{2}$, because the cosine is positive from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The first ring outside the middle bump starts where $r^2=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and ends where $r^2=\frac{5\pi}{2}$. The next ring starts where $r^2=2\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}$, and so on. There are origin additional rings closer and closer together as the distance from the origin increases.

If you know how to use polar (cylindrical) coordinates, it shouldn’t be too hard to express the integral over the volume under a given one of the rings (or under the central bump), because the integrand and the regions are simpler to express in terms of the cylindrical coordinates $r,\theta,$ and $z$. (They don’t depend on $\theta$ at all.)

If you get a nice enough answer, maybe you can write the entire integral as an infinite series that you can find the sum of.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer